# Angular|RxJS - Type-ahead search request gets cancelled by browser (on click)

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

I am new to RxJS (and frontend) but I know that `switchMap()` in the following code is used to break and re-run a search request as the user types into a text box. Search works fine, the only problem is that if the user clicks anywhere outside the textbox (like anywhere on the page, or on a different browser tab or window, or chrome devtools) after entering the text and before the request is fulfilled, the browser cancels the search request altogether.

(Note: The search request is cancelled and re-run correctly if user keeps typing while the request is being processed. Only click event causes the complete request cancellation without re-run)

[image]

```js
  search = (input: Observable<string>) => {
    return input.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((text) => text.length < 2 ? this.clearDropDown() // clear dropdown showing list of item names.
        : this.onKeyUp(text).pipe(
          map(result => {
           this.spinnerService.end(); // stop loading spinner.
          if (results.data) {
              return results.data; // return list of item names for the dropdown.
          }
      })
        )));
  }

  onKeyUp(text: string): Observable<any> {
      this.spinnerService.start(); // start loading spinner animation overlay on the page.
      return this.http.post(this.apiUrlString, { 'itemName': text }); // this search request works fine.
  }
```

The HTML, in case it is relevant:

```html
    <div>
      <input
        id="itemSearchValue"
        type="text"
        class="form-control/bg-light/rounded/dropdown-toggle"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
        (selectItem)="onSelectItem($event)" // irrelevant to the question.
        formControlName="itemSearchValue"
        [ngbTypeahead]="search"
        #instance="ngbTypeahead" />
    </div>
```

How can I make sure the request is not cancelled by the browser when the user emits clicks somewhere? I'd like to keep the `switchMap()` method.

Comment: A small question, why are you mixing reactive forms with template-driven? Either remove `[(ngModel)]` for template driven model or use `formControlName` for reactive only.

Comment: This is pre-existing code that someone else wrote. I'm trying not to touch it, and it seems to not be related to my issue.

Comment: Is an event fired on blur or what ? Could you check with a tap(console.log) in the pipe ?

Comment: The search request is initiated after the user enters >2 letters, and if you click anywhere (like on a different tab, different window, or even chrome devtools) before the request is fulfilled, the request is cancelled by the browser. I think the `tap()` is run before the request is initiated.

Comment: Edited description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all subscriptions are being cancelled `onBlur`

From the github: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.ts

```js
  handleBlur() {
    this._resubscribeTypeahead.next(null);
    this._onTouched();
  }
```

So the solution is to not let the type-ahead have access to the network request subscription. Just subscribe within the component and pass a reference to the data instead.

```js
  data: string[] = [];
  sub = new Subscription();

  search = (input: Observable<string>) => {
    return input.pipe(
      debounceTime(500), // half second buffer before request starts
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((text) => {
        if (text.length < 2) {
          this.clearDropDown(); // clear dropdown showing list of item names.
          return [];
        }
        this.subscribeToKeyUp(text); // update data
        return [this.data];
      })
    );
  };

  subscribeToKeyUp(text: string) {
    this.sub.unsubscribe(); // cancel if a request is still going
    this.spinnerService.start(); // start loading spinner animation overlay on the page.
    this.sub = this.onKeyUp(text).subscribe((results) => {
      if (results?.data) this.data = results.data;
      this.spinnerService.end(); // stop loading spinner.
    });
  }

  onKeyUp(text: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrlString, { itemName: text });
  }
```

Here's a stackblitz that simulates a 3 second delay between request and response. Clicking off between the half second debounce time and the 3 second response still allows the request to complete.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgyadh?file=src/app/typeahead-basic.ts

**P.S.** I saw that you mentioned requests can take 30+ seconds, in that case I'd make a button to call `subscribeToKeyUp(text)` and remove that call from the `search` function. That way the massive request doesn't get triggered on every letter. Just a suggestion anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have my work PC on me right now, but I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Worth noting that the stackblitz example no longer works but this seems to be because the toolcarton.com API now redirects to spam networks.